# Vue: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function" - ($emit inside jQuery listener callback)

Tags: vue.js, scope, event-listener

I have initialized a jQuery plugin on an element inside a vue component. In the intialization function I have a "`$(document).ready(function()`" , which means that "`this`" won't work inside. So I use var `that = this`.

However there is also a listener registered, and inside that listener I need to emit a value:

```
initialize() {

     var that = this;

    $(document).ready(function() {

       let editor = that.$refs.myplugin

      //initialize   
       var $editor  = $(editor ).myplugin({

            height: 300
       })

       //listener callback
       $editor.on('myplugin.change', (e) => {

           //results in error
           that.$emit('input', 'test message');

        }) 
    }) 
}
```

The value does get emitted, but each time there is the error "Error in v-on handler: "`TypeError: handler.apply is not a function`". If I comment out the $emit, there is no error.

So `that` works inside the callback (I can call a test function), but **not** emit.

So why is the error showing and how do I use `$emit` correclty in that listener callback ?

**Update**:
Tried to change the arrow function into normal function , but still the same error.

Comment: try changing `$editor.on` event arrow function to normal function

Comment: Sounded like a good idea, but it actually didn't work..